# php: how to search the url in a switch case and echo always something different for every url?

Tags: php

i got the code below to find the url of the site and this works.  But I want a `switch` statement to search this url in a list and echo something else in for every url.

```
$actual_link = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

Comment: Where is the code and what is the problem ?

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: I make a plugin in wordpress and I need to echo another value for every url (for every customer a personal message)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand the question, this looks like what you are looking for:

```
switch ($actual_link) {
    case 'http://domain/something1/':
        echo 'Something 1';
        break;
    case 'http://domain/something2/':
        echo 'SomeSthing 2';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'default';
}
```